# How do debuggers manage to break on any throw?

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, exception, gdb

In GDB and other debuggers it's possible to ask the debugger (using `catch throw`) to stop anytime an exception is thrown before the process passes said exception to the respective exception handler.

By what mechanism is this possible? Is there an OS signal that can be used to hook in? Is there a function pointer to monkey patch to allow this? Does it single step to make this happen?

Is this mechanism otherwise available outside the debugger?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

GDB sets a breakpoint on the library function which does the stack unwinding (`__cxa_throw()` for x86_64) to implement `catch throw`. It will use the same mechanism to set this breakpoint it uses to set any other type of code breakpoint.

> By what mechanism is this possible? Is there an OS signal that can be used to hook in? Is there a function pointer to monkey patch to allow this? Does it single step to make this happen?

None of these. It is just a normal breakpoint on `__cxa_throw()`. GDB uses knowledge of the implementation of the C++ runtime, with all the disadvantages that brings. C++ exceptions are below the radar of the operating system, so the operating system would not know about them. The confusion stems from the fact that certain signals (e.g. segfaults) are called *exceptions* on Windows and can be handled in a very similar way to C++ exceptions on Windows when debugging. But this is making OS-signals (e.g. segfault) behaving like C++ exceptions, not the other way round.

See also ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_node/gdb_30.html

Comment: On GNU/Linux and at least x86_64, gdb's `catch throw` actually sets a breakpoint on `__cxa_throw`, and `catch catch` sets one on `__cxa_begin_catch`.

Comment: It seems the function names I mentioned are actually mandated for Intel architecture by the [Itanium C++ ABI](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi-eh.html) – note that MS Windows is the only major platform *not* to follow this ABI on said architecture.

Comment: @Arne: Thanks for the info. I will update the answer.